# ord() does not work after slash

Tags: php, decimal, ascii

I use this following function to convert ASCII to Decimal:

```
function ascii_to_dec($str)
{
  echo $str."<br />";
  for ($i = 0, $j = strlen($str); $i < $j; $i++) 
  {
    $dec_array[$i] = ord($str[$i]);
  }
return $dec_array;
}
```

Example:

```
$ascii ="2010/";
$newvar = ascii_to_dec($ascii);
```

And call the function using this code.

It works well with the data I send as above. But when I give the data such as:

```
$ascii ="2010/2012";
```

Only up to `2010/` is converted. The data after the `/` is omitted. How to convert the full data I pass to the function?

Comment: I tried your code and the result is as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue. $dec_array suffers from memory issue I believe. The Decimal equivalent for 2010/2012 is "504849484750484950". But $newvar gets only upto 504849484 which is actually for 2010/.

Altered my code to below,

```
function ascii_to_dec($str)
{
echo $str."<br />";
echo strlen($str); echo "<br />";
for ($i = 0, $j = strlen($str); $i < $j; $i++) {
$temp = ord($str[$i]);
$decimal="$decimal"."$temp";
}
return $decimal;
}
```

Now it returns as a text.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you weren't showing the full code in your question then. See my answer for an equivalent but shorter solution.

Answer (score 3):

This probably doesn't explain why your code behaves strangely, but you could rewrite your whole function as:

```
function ascii_to_dec($str) {
    return array_values(unpack('C*', $str));
}
```

**update**

```
function ascii_to_dec($str) {
    return join('', unpack('C*', $str));
}
```